# print a struct pointer and a deferenced struct member

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, printf

hello all i am new to programming,i have a paradigm where i need to print a pointer of type struct which gets the value dynamically in each iteration and also print a defrenced struct member on each iteration.

```
struct my_struct
{
int x;
int y;
}
void function(){

my_struct* a=value.get() // some values will be assigned dynamically to this pointer from other part of function.

my_struct* data = new thread_data;
data->x=1 //which will get updated according the iterations and conditions
data->y=2 //which will get updated according the iterations and conditions

}
```

now i need to print the values of a,x,y in the caller function, How to print those values. 
some what like

```
printf("a=%lx x=%i y=%i\n", a,x,y);
```

can someone please give me some ideas or how to proceed? thanks alot

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointers. Check `man 3 printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you can use `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << "a=" << a << " x=" << a->x << " y=" << a->y << "\n";
```

Otherwise, your `printf` version can be fixes like this:

```
printf("a=%p x=%i y=%i\n",  a, a->x, a->y);
```

Comment: Seeing as there's `new` and `.get()` in the OP's code, there's perhaps no need to mention `printf()`.

Comment: @Angew the `printf` came straight from OP's code. I was trying to fix their version.

Comment: `std::cout << "a=" << a << " x=" << a->x << " y=" << a->y << "\n";` just giving the a will give the value stored in `my_struct* a `? or the address stored in `my_struct* a`?

Comment: @Rd7 it will give the address that `a` points to in hexadecimal format.

Comment: @Rd7: Both! The variable `a` is a pointer, and its value is a memory address.

Comment: @juanchopanzaBut i need the value stored in the pointer `my_struct* a` sorry i am little confused

Comment: @Rd7 the value stored in the pointer *is* the address it points to.

Comment: @BenHymersSo i will get both the value and the address of `my_struct* a`??

Comment: @Rd7 you get only the value, i.e the address of the `my_struct` it points to. If you want the *address* of the pointer itself, you need to print `&a`.